# searching for a certain word in all tables and columns in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering if there is anyway to search for a certain word or phrase in all tables/rows in SQL.

I have tried,

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE column_name LIKE '%WORD%'
;
```

However, this doesn't bring back what I want.

My desired output would be this query bringing back 'WORD' that is in all tables and all columns and all rows. I know its a very general search which may bring back a lot of data but I need to search for a certain word and have no idea which table/column this word is in.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://community.oracle.com/message/14534461

Answer (score 0):

Try this in case you are searching for columns

```
SELECT * from dba_objects WHERE
object_name like '%WORD%'
```

Comment: This doesn't search an object, just a system view.

Comment: The question is about finding the contents of tables, i.e. dynamically querying every string column of every table.